# Is it possible to build a native Ubuntu app without using the qt framework?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, desktop-application

I want to build a native Ubuntu desktop app, so the Unity 7/8 graphics shell, without using the qt Framework. I know that Unity uses qt for it's widget library but does that mean I have to use the qt framework as well? If not what approach should I be thinking about.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve, more specifically? Access some spesific Unity Desktop features? Or why do you want to be limited to this particular environment?

Comment: Also, why don't you want to use Qt for this, why ate you looking for an alternative?

Comment: I want to develop a commercial application but the cost of a commercial licence for the Qt framework is prohibitive. I was wondering if this is possible though language bindings etc... to achieve a native looking UI and possibly integrate further with things like convergence.

Comment: Using LGPL version of Qt is no problem in a commercial application, thats kinda what LGPL is all about (just be sure to not use the recent GPL-licensed modules, stick to the LGPL stuff). In particular, if you are developing for Unity, and assuming Ubuntu has not changed its Qt library licensing, you don't even need to ship Qt libraries at all, just add dependency to Ubuntu libs to a .deb.

Comment: In the end I used the GTK framework and Vala. It's very nice to work with and runs fast, looks like a native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "native". Native as in "hardware native" or native as in "software native"?

The Ubuntu SDK is based on Qt, so if you want a software native, you'd have to go that way, but if you want "hardware native" there are alternative frameworks which can produce platform native binaries.

Comment: In order to produce a UI the native binaries would need to interact with existing programs running on the machine and I'm not familiar with how those interactions would restrict me in terms of language/framework options. (I'm currently investigating Rust with Qt bindings and trying to figure out the implications of Qt licensing).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!  There are multiple frameworks for this.  Try Atom/Electron, JSqwing, PyGame.. just to name a few!

Comment: I am considering Electron as an option if I can't find anything with a more native looking UI.

Comment: Even though it isn't quite native, there is still a lot of cool tricks up its sleeve, and it can be suoee native-like.  I don't think the user will be able to tell the difference.  Check out the Atom text editor.  It's written in Electron.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's nothing forcing you to use Qt. However, nothing's forcing you to write for the Unity shell, either, so you really might want to ask yourself whether you want to limit yourself to Ubuntu in the first place.